# Add administrable image for a page in Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 and i created a page where i display an image and a form inside a block as an inline template. 
This looks like this :

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right:0px; padding-left:0px;">
  <img src="{{ base_path ~ directory }}/sites/default/files/Dinard_S.jpg" id="b-frm-img" style="width: 400px; height:300px;"></div>
```

Then another div contains my form. What i'm trying to do is to make user with no code knowledge able to change this specific image from the drupal admin.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an admin page to upload an image in a dedicated folder using managed_file type in the form. Seems there is no better ways.